# Why would LSTM with one time step perform better than MLP?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, regression, lstm, mlp

Out of curiosity, I compared a stacked LSTM neural network with a single time step with MLP with tanh activation function, thinking they would have the same performance.
The architectures used for comparison are as follows, and they are trained on an identical dataset of regression problem (loss function is MSE):

```
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=num_features, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dense(150, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1))


model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, num_features)))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(150, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

Surprisingly, the loss for the LSTM model decreases much faster than the MLP:

```
MLP loss:
Epoch: 1
Training Loss: 0.011504
Validation Loss: 0.010708
Epoch: 2
Training Loss: 0.010739
Validation Loss: 0.010623
Epoch: 3
Training Loss: 0.010598
Validation Loss: 0.010189
Epoch: 4
Training Loss: 0.010046
Validation Loss: 0.009651
Epoch: 5
Training Loss: 0.009305
Validation Loss: 0.008502
Epoch: 6
Training Loss: 0.007388
Validation Loss: 0.004334
Epoch: 7
Training Loss: 0.002576
Validation Loss: 0.001686
Epoch: 8
Training Loss: 0.001375
Validation Loss: 0.001217
Epoch: 9
Training Loss: 0.000921
Validation Loss: 0.000916
Epoch: 10
Training Loss: 0.000696
Validation Loss: 0.000568
Epoch: 11
Training Loss: 0.000560
Validation Loss: 0.000479
Epoch: 12
Training Loss: 0.000493
Validation Loss: 0.000451
Epoch: 13
Training Loss: 0.000439
Validation Loss: 0.000564
Epoch: 14
Training Loss: 0.000402
Validation Loss: 0.000478
Epoch: 15
Training Loss: 0.000377
Validation Loss: 0.000366
Epoch: 16
Training Loss: 0.000351
Validation Loss: 0.000240
Epoch: 17
Training Loss: 0.000340
Validation Loss: 0.000352
Epoch: 18
Training Loss: 0.000327
Validation Loss: 0.000203
Epoch: 19
Training Loss: 0.000311
Validation Loss: 0.000323
Epoch: 20
Training Loss: 0.000299
Validation Loss: 0.000264
```

```
LSTM loss:
Epoch: 1
Training Loss: 0.011345
Validation Loss: 0.010634
Epoch: 2
Training Loss: 0.008128
Validation Loss: 0.003692
Epoch: 3
Training Loss: 0.001488
Validation Loss: 0.000668
Epoch: 4
Training Loss: 0.000440
Validation Loss: 0.000232
Epoch: 5
Training Loss: 0.000260
Validation Loss: 0.000160
Epoch: 6
Training Loss: 0.000200
Validation Loss: 0.000137
Epoch: 7
Training Loss: 0.000165
Validation Loss: 0.000093
Epoch: 8
Training Loss: 0.000140
Validation Loss: 0.000104
Epoch: 9
Training Loss: 0.000127
Validation Loss: 0.000139
Epoch: 10
Training Loss: 0.000116
Validation Loss: 0.000091
Epoch: 11
Training Loss: 0.000106
Validation Loss: 0.000095
Epoch: 12
Training Loss: 0.000099
Validation Loss: 0.000082
Epoch: 13
Training Loss: 0.000091
Validation Loss: 0.000135
Epoch: 14
Training Loss: 0.000085
Validation Loss: 0.000099
Epoch: 15
Training Loss: 0.000082
Validation Loss: 0.000055
Epoch: 16
Training Loss: 0.000079
Validation Loss: 0.000062
Epoch: 17
Training Loss: 0.000075
Validation Loss: 0.000045
Epoch: 18
Training Loss: 0.000073
Validation Loss: 0.000121
Epoch: 19
Training Loss: 0.000069
Validation Loss: 0.000045
Epoch: 20
Training Loss: 0.000065
Validation Loss: 0.000052
```

After 100 epochs, the validation loss for MLP decreased to about 1e-4, but the loss for LSTM decreased to about 1e-5.
It doesn't make much sense to me as to how these two architectures would be any different, since the LSTM cells are not using any memory from previous timesteps. Also, the training for MLP is about 3 times faster than LSTM. Could someone explain the math behind it?

Comment: Why are you using return-sequences? Seems weird if you're actually just inputting a single sample. Also, are you sure that you are resetting the hidden state of the LSTMs between every sample?

Comment: Cause if I don't use them it wouldn't run. I thought if you would have multiple LSTM layers with different neurons you must use return sequences. The sample size is about 450k, with 7 input features and 1 timestep (no time series). I'm not sure what you mean by resetting the hidden state of the LSTMs between every sample. Do I need to make it stateful?

Comment: `return sequences=False` is equivalent to returning the last timestep's hidden step, to feed that into an LSTM, you need an additional extension of the Sequence dimension that you previously removed. With regard to your question: An LSTM and an MLP are NOT equivalent for a sequence length of 1. The output and input gates do still operate between layers. You can see this if you compare the equations for both.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML math, theory, and methodology.

Comment: @runDOSrun Thank you. That makes more sense. I should look into the differences in equations.